# Conditional join to a table based on column value

Tags: sql, join, sql-server-2008-r2

We have the following table which contains `deviceId` and `customerPrefix` columns.

```
tblDeviceInfo: 
deviceId       customerPrefix
1             ABC
2             XYZ
```

Based on the customer prefix we also have device tables, I have listed only 2 below but we have too many of them and the above tblDeviceInfo table can contain many different customerPrefixes, I know this is a bad practice but this is what we have at the moment and we have to work with it for the time being.

```
tblDeviceABC
deviceId           deviceName
1              NameABC1
2              NameABC2

tblDeviceXYZ
deviceid           deviceName
1             NameXYZ1
2             NameXYZ2
```

When I am querying the tblDeviceInfo (which can contain quite a few rows) I would like to be able to get the following:

```
deviceId, deviceName, customerPrefix
1            NameABC1          ABC
2            NameXYZ1          XYZ
```

Currently we get everything from the tblDeviceInfo table, start looping (in C# app) and get the device details from the relevant table based on the customer prefix, 
I was wondering if there is a way of joining to a table based on the column value and get everything back with one sql like this with dynamic sql

```
    @sql = 'Select deviceId, customerPrefix From tblDeviceInfo i
  INNER JOIN tblDevice' + d.customerPrefix + ' d ON d.deviceId = i.deviceId'
```

This is not quite right but is there anyway of achieving this with dynamic sql or with any other way?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It's not just bad practice, it is awful.

But, you might be able to solve the query something like this:

```
Select deviceId, customerPrefix From tblDeviceInfo i
LEFT OUTER JOIN tblDeviceABC dABC ON dABC.deviceId = i.deviceId
...
LEFT OUTER JOIN tblDeviceXYZ dXYZ ON dXYZ.deviceId = i.deviceId
```

There will be a lot of null checking on the result, but you should be able to make it in one (expensive) query.

Answer (score 0):

You can `union` all the `tblDEVICE` in a subquery andjoin it with the infor table,

```
SELECT  b.*, a.customerPrefix
FROM    tblDeviceInfo a
        INNER JOIN
        (
            SELECT deviceID, deviceName From tblDeviceABC
            UNION
            SELECT deviceID, deviceName From tblDeviceXYZ
        ) b ON a.deviceID = b.deviceID
```